# Getting error in a like condition (Filter)

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Using VB.Net and Sql Server

Query

```
Select cCustomerCode,cCustomerName from cms_Customer where cCustomerName like '%['" & frmCustomers.txtName.Text & "']%'
```

The above query is showing error as "Incorret syntax near a"

What is problem with above query, whethere like condition is used properly or not.

Need Query or Code Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
str="Select cCustomerCode,cCustomerName FROM cms_Customer
     where cCustomerName like '%" & frmCustomers.txtName.Text & "%'"
```

OR

```
str="Select cCustomerCode,cCustomerName FROM cms_Customer
         where cCustomerName like @custName"
.....
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custName","%" & txtName.Text & "%")
```

Answer (score 0):

[ is a special character in SQL server, you need to escape it

```
\[
```

See here http://web.archive.org/web/20150519072547/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com:80/how-do-i-search-for-special-characters-e-g-in-sql-server.html